# Schemas validation tool reports errors

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-admin-sdk

I'm trying out the new schema in gmail feature. 
This is the `json-ld` format I embedded into my email message.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "schema.org",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ViewAction",
    "url": "https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema",
    "name": "Open link"
  }
}
</script>
```

I tried to validate it using the tools here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/testing-your-schema and it doesn't seem to like what I have got there.  Here are the two errors I had:

- The property action cannot be used with the CreativeWork type
- Unknown type ViewAction

I understand that 'action' is not an officially supported property as defined in http://schema.org/CreativeWork but I'm not sure whether it's some kind of problem with my json-ld data or it's just that the validation tool hasn't been updated to include the new properties yet.

Are there anyone who can comment on this?

Answer (score 2):

The validator warns directly above it that it is still in alpha.

Claudio Cherubino in a reply on the [introduction post on the GApps Developer Blog](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/introducing-actions-in-inbox-powered-by.html) states

> the validator is still in alpha and not all the new things we
>   introduced are already supported. Please bear with us a little more
>   while we add them.

Some of Google's own examples don't correctly validate yet.

Comment: That's correct, the tool doesn't support all new types yet, but it can still be used to check what properties are extracted from the markup